# Using crossdomain.xml when serving a .swf from a domain that is NOT the domain of the web page it appears on

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, crossdomain.xml

I'm writing a Flash script that will need to pull data from Domain A, is hosted on Domain B, and appears on the web page of Domain C (.swf is pulled from Domain B).

My question is this - I have limited abilities to modify the crossdomain.xml file on Domain A - will things work if I tell Domain A's crossdomain.xml to allow calls from Domain B but not Domain C?

Comment: You can get past the limited cross domain issue by caching the data using a server side script as mihai advises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work as the domain of the SWF is B, not C. I assume you will just embed it there, won't you?

Comment: Yeah the embed in Domain C will load the SWF from Domain B.  I just wasn't sure which one mattered in a situation like that.

Answer (score 1):

the call to pull data from domain A is from the swf whos url is from domain B

http://www.domainB.com/my.swf     is loading    http://www.domainA.com/api.php

http://www.domainA.com/crossdomain.xml needs to allow domainB